# Can I use Windows-Authentification from IIS to authenticate to TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, windows-authentication

I've got a .NET-Webservice written in C# which uses Windows-Authentification. So when I'm connecting to my webservice to use a webmethod, I'm getting the login-form first, where I can write my username and password. This authentification works correctly but now, I want to use THAT authentification to login to the Team Foundation Server (Yes they are the same). Is there any possibility to use the windows-credentials or the authentification in my C#-Code to forward them to the TfsTeamProjectCollection-object?

That's how I connect for now:

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(tfsUsername, password);
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsURL), credentials);
tfs.Authenticate();
```

So now, I want to use somehow my windows-authentification to forward them to the constructor of the TfsTeamProjectCollection, instead of using my NetworkCredential credentials object.

Any information about that would be very nice. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Check Kerberos delegation materials from Microsoft TechNet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we impersonate Windows user to TFS or TFS web access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318497/can-we-impersonate-windows-user-to-tfs-or-tfs-web-access)

Answer (score 0):

You may check the reply from @MrHinsh in this case [Access TFS via its API using Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894813/access-tfs-via-its-api-using-windows-authentication):

You have two options to resolve it:

1. Host your mvc web app on the same server as tfs
2. Configure Active Directory to allow your servers identity to delegate the logged in user credentials to another service.